# File dialog in Chrome does not remember last folder

Tags: nautilus, google-chrome

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04, and there are so many issues that negatively impact my productivity. Most of them are related to nautilus.

In Chrome, when I navigate to a path for uploading (or saving) files, the path is lost when I upload the next file. I have to navigate again to the same folder for each file I select.

How can I make the file dialog remember the last path used? This should be the default whenever uploading or saving a file - it should just continue from where I was the last time I saved/uploaded a file.
I am not looking for workarounds, as suggested in other topics (such as copying the path or creating bookmarks).

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Who in their right mind decided to change this? If it ain't broke don't fix.

Comment: 100% agree. This renders Chrome nearly unusable in some situations.

Comment: are you using the *flatpak* version of Chrome ("flatpak-Chrome")? If so, then the issue you are facing could be coming from the flatpak-Chrome's default *restricted* filesystem access permission settings. Using e.g. *Flatseal*, you can grant flatpak-Chrome permissions to access the filesystem.

Answer (score -3):

The workaround below got me close to the original functionality. I am running Ubuntu 22.04.

**Workaround**

1. Settings > Privacy > File History & Trash
2. Set File History Duration to 1 day
3. Click Clear History

Now, when you do a file and select, the Recents list of files will be much shorter and you are more likely to find the last file(s) you selected. I can survive with this workaround.

Comments:

- While typing this, you could potentially write a script to clear your
  history automatically ever N seconds.
- The sources I list further down are all the posts I found regarding this topic.

**Attempted Solution 1**

This solution was unsucessful.

With the dconf-editor, set one of these settings to 'cwd' and restart the system. You will find that this does not fix the issue.

```
/org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/startup-mode

/org/gtk/gtk4/settings/file-chooser/startup-mode
```

Comments:

- I have Red Hat Linux 7.6. On this RHEL system I have startup-mode set
  to the default value of 'recent' and the file and select option
  remembers the last opened directory. The issue seems to be exclusive
  to Ubuntu 22.04.

Sources:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/1698031/gtk3-file-chooser-and-recent-directory-setup
2. [Firefox snap doesn't remember upload path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415380/firefox-snap-doesnt-remember-upload-path)
3. [How can I have nautilus open to previously used directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425311/how-can-i-have-nautilus-open-to-previously-used-directory)
4. https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2160654.html