# Firefox snap doesn't remember upload path

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, snap

I am using Xubuntu 22.04 with Firefox installed as a snap.

When I upload files to a site, the browser doesn't remember the last upload path. When I need to upload many files, I have to go through the path every time.

The file picker opens showing "Recent Files" every time.

It is very inconvenient if I want to attach many files. I have to browse to the directory each time.

Is there any setting to fix it?

Comment: It is some snap bug I guess.

Comment: It is using standard privacy settings.

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: Same issue... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421712/firefox-behavior-on-upload-of-files-after-upgrade-from-snap so it might indeed not be fixable :-( I hate snaps :+

Comment: It should be fixable somehow. But it may require updating snap, etc. I can switch to deb, but it is the first comp I upgraded to 22.04 for testing. I'll leave it as is and see if it is fixed sometime.

Comment: I suspect the upload path is read-only there. Does anyone know where it is stored?

Comment: Bread crumb: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/firefox-v-101-0-2-download-directory-always-changes-to-run-user-1000-doc/30395 . Firefox, whether snap or not, should attempot to save the last-used location from the file-picker in `/run/user/<user_id>/`, which is managed by xdg-desktop-portal (not Firefox, not Snap). So it might --or might not-- be an xdg-desktop-portal bug.

Comment: @user535733 But regular deb FF is OK, so it is a snap bug.

Comment: I would recommend filing a bug report on it. Perhaps I missed the traffic on snapcraft.io and Launchpad, but I didn't see much about this issue. The snap developers are on a bug-fixing frenzy *right now*, so get it in front of them!

Comment: This is a critical bug. It makes snap browsers unusable for use cases when a lot of files need to be uploaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a bug in snap. It is a design flaw in xdg-desktop-portal, which Firefox uses to access files outside the container it runs in. This is a flatpak technology which snaps are optionally able to use.

Whenever Firefox wants to access a file outside the container, it shows a file requester where the user can select the file. Gtk and Qt are patched so that whenever a containerized application opens a file requester, they send a DBus request to the desktop portal which makes it show the file requester instead.

The portal then copies the selected file into a directory that Firefox does have access to, and returns the path of that temporary file instead of the one the user selected. This is sent back over DBus to Gtk or Qt, which returns the temporary path from the file requester call.

The intent of this system is to make the portal transparent to applications. But the problem with this is that there is no way for the application or the user to know that an intermediate process has interfered with the selected path.

So there is no way for Firefox to "remember" the directory you selected in the file requester because it never receives it.

The same thing happens when downloading: Firefox is not able to know the location you selected, so clicking on "open file" will open the temporary download location, not the final location. This can lead to data loss if you click "open file" and make changes to the temporary file without realising it is not the copy in the final location, because those temporary files presumably get deleted eventually.

Comment: Intriging :) +1 :) I wonder if there is a way to intervene dbus?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the Firefox snap-store version. I've tested the snap-store version of firefox and I've noticed that it has that same problem. This doesn't seem fixable, but I suggest installing Firefox from the Ubuntu Software Store, or from https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?redirect_source=firefox-com. That version doesn't seem to have that same issue.

Comment: I know that non-snap version works well ;-)