# Firefox behavior on upload of files after upgrade from snap

Tags: firefox, snap, upload

After upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04, firefox changed behaviour when uploading files to a website. It consequently opens at the home folder instead of the last used folder. This is quite annoying since uploading photos to a website is really tiresome clicking through all the folders on and on again. This was not the case in 20.04. There it remembered the last used folder. I have another computer on 20.04 and tried to install the snap version and the same behaviour here. Any solutions ?

Comment: I made a fresh install on a Virtual machine with 22.04. Firefox behave as expected here. Wierd.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/a/1423497/15811

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

I've tested now, ubuntu 22 on virtualbox 6.1.
I've uploaded a test file from my home folder.
Closed and reopened firefox.
After that, if I upload another file it open nautilus on the recent tab.
So this is a bug of the firefox snap version.

If you have determined that this problem happen only with the snap version of firefox, why you not remove it and use the version from the mozilla ppa instead?

```
sudo snap remove firefox

printf "Package: *\nPin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam\nPin-Priority: 1001" >> mozilla-firefox 
sudo mv mozilla-firefox /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox

printf 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' >> 51unattended-upgrades-firefox
sudo mv 51unattended-upgrades-firefox /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firefox -y
```

Comment: That did it. I was not aware of the PPA for firefox. But still there is some weird things going on with firefox's transition to snap !

Comment: @larsbrandi If this answer has fixed your issue perhaps you could 'Accept' it by clicking on the tick or check mark...

Comment: It this is not another symptom of the [Firefox native messaging bug](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-native-messaging-support-in-the-firefox-snap/29759), then please report it!