# Snap Firefox on 22.04 doesn't remember saved image locations

Tags: firefox, snap

I have recently updated my Ubuntu to the 22.04.1 LTS version, and I have updated my Firefox to the new Snap version alongside with it. Whenever I save an image using this new setup, it doesn't remember my save location for files of like kind. For example, when I download a PNG image, it always defaults to the same location in `/run/user/1000/doc`. My image does save normally to the requested location, but a copy is made in its own folder `/doc`. When I download a new PNG image, it does not remember the location I saved the previous image and returns to the `/doc` folder. Why does this happen?

Comment: (I don't know why it happens but) You can switch to the apt package to fix the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firefox snap doesn't remember upload path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415380/firefox-snap-doesnt-remember-upload-path). Same xdg-desktop-portal issue: Download instead of upload.

Comment: And the Mozilla bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1775497 , there is your answer to "why".

Comment: Huh, that would make sense. Thank you!