# How can I have nautilus open to previously used directory?

Tags: nautilus, 22.04

Before I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 on my System76 mini (Meerkat), I was running Ubuntu 20.04.

Before upgrading to 22.04, when I went to upload a file to a website (something I do constantly for my work), the file-finder window (I don't know the tech names of such things, but I have the sense after searching around that this window might be a component of the nautilus system:  I can't be sure) used to open to wherever in the file system I last uploaded a file from using whatever program I used.  For example, if using program X, I last uploaded from /this1/location1, and if using program Y, I last uploaded a file from /this2/location2, then when I went next to upload with program X, the file-finder window would open in /this1/location1, and when I next to upload with program Y, the file-finder window would open in /this2/location2.

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, whenever I go, from any program, to upload, the file-finder window opens in the Recent directory.  I never use the Recent directory and it is full of all sorts of things I generally won't need when I must upload a file.

How can I get the old behavior back?

I have tried to find answers on discussion boards online, but generally it seems people who have asked about related issues have been told to tinker with the settings in an alleged .desktop configuration in ~/.local/share/applications.  But, I find no such file.

What do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firefox snap doesn't remember upload path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415380/firefox-snap-doesnt-remember-upload-path)

Comment: No.  I don't know what snap is.  The problem described does seem to be the same sort of problem I am experiencing, but I can't say that any of the comments about what might (or might not) be done are very helpful because I don't really understand them.  All of them seem to be about something called snap.  What is that?

Comment: Nothing can be done but installing FF as a deb, not as a snap as it is in Ubuntu 22.04.